# dbfunctions.truncatetime does not truncate time

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am using linq to query a table based on a DateType.Date field. I'm also truncating the time part of the target date. When I look at the logs, I see a query like below.

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[MemberId] AS [MemberId], 
[Extent1].[StepCount] AS [StepCount], 
[Extent1].[Calories] AS [Calories], 
[Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Extent1].[LogTime] AS [LogTime], 
[Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Extent1].[InsertTime] AS [InsertTime], 
[Extent1].[DeleteTime] AS [DeleteTime]
FROM [dbo].[StepLog] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (([Extent1].[DeleteTime] IS NULL) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_1 IS NOT NULL)) AND ([Extent1].[Date] = (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102))) AND ([Extent1].[MemberId] = @p__linq__1)
-- DynamicFilterParam_1: 'null' (Type = Boolean)
-- p__linq__0: '4/9/2016 3:13:58 PM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- p__linq__1: '26ad5c83-d2c3-4894-b18a-3a4477f9f176' (Type = Guid, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 4/10/2016 2:30:46 AM +00:00
```

-- Completed in 5 ms with result: SqlDataReader

As you can see, the date still had the time part in it. It seems that truncateTime function has no effect. What am I missing? I was expecting 4/9/2016 00:00:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are truncating the time in the WHERE-Clause only...

```
SELECT TOP 2
  ....
  CAST ([Extent1].[Date]  AS DATE) AS [Date], 
  ....
```